# Smooth scroll to ID using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Struggling to implement a smooth scroll feature when navigating to an ID using my navbar.  Instead, it makes the default jump, which is a bit of an eye sore.

I am very inexperienced using jQuery, so any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated.

I have made an attempt to get this implemented however, as I have said, it is 'jumping' as opposed to scrolling.

HTML

```
<li>
  <a href="#popular">Most Popular</a>
</li>
<div class="col-sm-12" id="popular">
<h3><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-fire"></i> Most Popular</h3>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#popular").on('click', function(event) {
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      event.preventDefault();
      var hash = this.hash;
      $('col-sm-12').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 800, function() {
        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    }
```

Comment: `$('col-sm-12')` is looking for a `<col-sm-12>` *tag*, which needless to say doesn't exist. Did you mean `$('.col-sm-12')`?

Comment: Have made that change, but still no difference. Thank you though!

Comment: You're also animating the scroll inside `.col-sm-12`, probably should be `$(window).animate`. And yet another issue, `$("#popular").on` should be `$("a").on`something more specific.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
  $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      var target = this.hash;
      var $target = $(target);

      $('html, body').stop().animate({
          'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
      }, 900, 'swing', function () {
          window.location.hash = target;
      });
  });
});
```

Add the above in your $(document).ready function in your jQuery file and all links which start with a # will have an animated scroll to the target.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try specifying the easing option.

Something like this:

```
$("#popular").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#popular").offset().top
    }, 800, 'linear');
});
```

Or:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#popular").on('click', function (e) {
        $('.col-sm-12').animate({
            scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
        }, 800);
    });
});
```

Comment: Still just jumping (the default), apologies.

Comment: Are you getting any javascript errors ? Also make sure your div has an opening "<".

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are trying to do with your Jquery but here's something you can try:     $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#popular").on('click', function (e) {
            $('.col-sm-12').animate({
                scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
            }, 800);
        });
    });

Comment: Still the same, unfortunately.